# How to apply changes done in my DataGridView back to the DataTable than to the Database?

Tags: mysql, winforms, datagrid, datagridview

Let me be specific:

I have the following components in my project:
1) Form
2) Textbox
3) Button
4) DataGridView
5) A class named Database - It has all the code stuff to interact with the database means it can insert,update,delete etc

I type the desired name in the textbox press the button and then a query is pass the database function to retrieve the desired data. My Database class always returns me the "SELECT" query results in a "DATATABLE".

I receive the "DATATABLE" in a variable called DataTable DT variable. I then write this code just dgv.datasource.DT then all my data is shown in the DataGridView.

Now the question is that how will the changes done in my dgv will be reflected in the datatable so than I can then pass my updated datatable back to the database.

This is my database code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace GSK.DBLayer
{
    class Database
    {
        //Declarations
        MySqlConnection conn;
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        MySqlDataAdapter da;
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb;
        DataTable DT;

        int pCount;
        string connectionString = "SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=gsk; UID=root;";
        //string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=GSK; Integrated Security=True";

        //Execute Queries
        public void AccessDB(string sqlQuery)
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Your request served successfully!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to serve your request!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        //Search Multiple Work
        public DataTable Search(string sqlQuery)
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

                conn.Open();

                da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
                cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
                DT = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(DT);

                conn.Close();
                da.Dispose(); //Memory Free...
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to access data!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            return DT;
        }


        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------



       //-----------------------------------------------------------------------


        //Get Max Product Count
        public int GetMaxPdCount(string sqlQuery)
        {
            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

                conn.Open();
                pCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                conn.Close();
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot Get Max Product Count!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            return pCount;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you get my question... I more thing is it necessary to use the adapter fill method to only fill the dataset not the datatable?

Answer (score 0):

May this will help you...

```
public DataTable returnTable(GridView gvName)
{ 
    DataTable dt=null;

    try
    {
        dt=(DataTable)gvName.DataSource;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Okay lets consider my changes are now in the datatable. Now how to pass this datatable to my database class so that I can update MYSQL database too?

Comment: I don't have your exact code...but i feel that this article may be helpful to you...Use Updatecommand of dataadapter to reflect your changed data in database....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y.aspx